# Heap Corruption Detected, where can I delete dynamic memory?

Tags: c++, memory, char, heap-corruption

I keep getting this error but I can't figure out when I can delete the dynamic memory for the variables: upSizedPlaintext, upsizedKey, upsizedCiphertext, or upsizedKeyD?

Since I am doing this for an assignment, I have to use BOOST tests and in the test that the lecturer will use, he will delete encryptedText and decrypted in the BOOST test. But I can't manage to find out where I can delete the variables from above. Any ideas and any help is greatly appreciated?

Also, I HAVE to use C-style strings not C++ strings.

Answer (score 2):

As you are returning pointers to new memory from encrypt and decrypt, the code calling those functions becomes responsible for calling `delete[]` on the pointers they receive.

Not a very good interface, and one reason why we like to use std::string in C++ code!

The usual source of heap corruption in C code is to forget the nul terminator for strings and allocate `strlen(s)` bytes instead of `strlen(s) + 1` bytes. I believe you do that in several places.

Comment: Plus other STL containers and smart pointers when we are not dealing with strings.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the same problem to me

```
char * decrypted = new char[lengthOfCiphertext];
```

should be

```
char * decrypted = new char[lengthOfCiphertext + 1];
```

Same issue in various places. Heap corruption is not because you are deleting at the wrong time, it's because you are writing outside of the bounds of allocated memory. In this case because you are allocating one too few bytes.

Comment: That's what I originally thought... And I had it like that originally as well but then I thought about it some more and didn't think it would work. After fixing that, where am I able to delete the variables mentioned?

Comment: There's only one answer to that. When you no longer need to use the memory. In your case it looks to me like you are doing it right in `encrypt`, when you leave this function you can no longer use the memory pointed to by `upsizedPlainText` and `upsizedKey` so deleting them is correct. But in `decrypt` you allocate memory but never delete it, so that's a memory leak. In general keeping track of when it is safe to delete memory is an extremely difficult thing to so. Yet another reason not to use heap allocation in the way you have been asked to do.

Comment: Ahhh, yes, I forgot to delete it after `decrypt` but I will add that now and fix it up.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to delete those variables anywhere they are visible. Since they are local variables inside a function, you can delete them anywhere inside that function, or in any function to which you pass those variables as pointers.

There's a big difference between where you can delete the memory pointed to by those pointers and where *should* delete those variables. There are lots of places where you shouldn't delete them. Deleting them in a function to which the variable is being passed is typically a bad idea. Deleting them before the function is finished using them is a very, very bad idea.

You should delete them somewhere between the last use and the return from the function that created them. If you don't delete them at all you have a memory leak, and if you delete them too early you have undefined behavior.